# Showing Splash screen in android apps

Tags: java, android, user-interface, apk, splash-screen

Have you ever seen the page in many apps that before launching the first activity appears and somehow it is like a waiting page ?! I am beginner to android and when I click on my apps , first a blank white page appears then after 3 seconds main activity comes out . but in many apps there is a kind of customised page before the first activity that is like a progress bar or sth . how can I customise that not so beautiful blank page before starting my app?! Thanx in advance .

Comment: You can show splash screen

Comment: this might help http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: Tnx I got it . I didn't know what it is .

Comment: @PedramYazdipour, the thing you are talking about is called **Spalsh Screen**. Please see my answer to get an idea about different way to doing doing it :)

Answer (score 3):

Technically thing you are talking about is called **splash screen**.

**Splash screen is used to show cold start where we can make our things ready to run an application. Google advocated to use it.**

There are few approaches to show splash screen.

1. You can use `CountDownTimer` like this. In `SplashActivity.java`

   ```
   private int TIME_OUT = 3000;
   ```

   ```
   CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TIME_OUT, TIME_OUT) {

   @Override
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
   {
       // Leave this
   }

   @Override
   public void onFinish()
   {
       // Start your app main activity
       Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);

       // close this activity
       finish();
   }
   ```

   }.start();
2. You can use `Handler` like this. In `SplashActivity.java`

   ```
   private static int TIME_OUT = 3000;

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
   {
       @Override
       public void run() {
               Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);

               finish();
           }
   ```

   }, TIME_OUT);
3. **Using theme - correct way of doing**

Add `background_splash.xml` file in drawable folder

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item>
       <bitmap
          android:gravity="center"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Add these lines in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Add these lines in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Finally add an activity called `SplashActivity.java` and add these code

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Splash Screen for this
Working code:

```
public class Mainsplash extends Activity {


     /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);




        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Mainsplash.this,MainActivity.class);
                Mainsplash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Mainsplash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }

}
```

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_src"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashimg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_v1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prg"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

And also in Manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".Mainsplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

use the intent filter for that  splash activity to make it launch first

hope this helps