# Splash Screen image background in LinearLayout not fit

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-xml, splash-screen

I used an image as a background of LinearLayout in splash screen activity but it show not fit for the screen. I don't know how to use attribute for it to stretching it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_image_background">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_image_background">
     <ImageView
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/my_image_background"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use ImageView and use attribute `scaleType` .This would automatically fit any screen resolution.

> ----- Update -------

As suggested by [Ahamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3026347/ahamed) Other than that if you want to add more Views into the layout , Its better to use `RelativeLayout` ( Since it would stack your views ).Consider the below implementation of RelativeLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <ImageView
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/my_image_background"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
          <!-- Add other views depending on your screen specs -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: he need background image. if he set the imageview in Linearlayout how can he place rest of the layouts? can you please explain?

Comment: @Ahamed I just gave a generic example for splash screen . One can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout , to get away with the problem stated by you.

Comment: Yes. you did it. i appreciate it. but, Some new basic programmers don't know what to do next.  so, give some more information on your answer then you will get better reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is this so use this instead, in your styles.xml add this:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

And in your Manifest file add this

```
  <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and  @drawable/splash could be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: if your image 'splash_logo' size is > 2k, you can scale it to fit your screen

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dighsplash">
</LinearLayout>
```

try this way.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use ImageView for image, so I have changed your layout as below & it shoul work as you expect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity"
android:fitSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:background="@drawable/my_image_background">
```

This code definitely fit your Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check the image `my_image_background` has any white spaces on the sides .if not , your code works...else u can try this code too

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/my_image_background">

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Check out this too:::
[Showing Splash screen in android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139777/showing-splash-screen-in-android-apps/43141041?noredirect=1#comment73409405_43141041)

Answer (score 0):

Try following if scaleType="fitxy" doesn't work with imageview.

**android:fitSystemWindows="true"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.myproject.SplashActivity"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="@drawable/my_image_background"
 android:fitSystemWindows="true">
```

Comment: what is the need here fillviewport=true. i think it is scrollview property. edit your answer.